# Apache Kerberos Auth file fallback

Tags: apache, file, kerberos, mod-auth-kerb

I've set up a Kerberos Authentication on my Apache Server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) with mod_auth_kerb.
The configuration is as follows :

```
AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "Authentication Required"
KrbAuthRealm MY.DOMAIN
Krb5KeyTab "/path/to/keytab"
KrbMethodK5Passwd On
Require valid-user
```

It works fine as it is.

But I want to add an authentication fallback to an .htpasswd file, in case of a Kerberos failure.

I tried the following :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthBasicProvider kerberos file
KrbAuthRealm MY.DOMAIN
Krb5KeyTab "/path/to/keytab"
KrbMethodK5Passwd On
KrbAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But I have an error when restarting :

```
apache2[7455]: Unknown Authn provider: kerberos
```

I've set my Apache LogLevel to debug but I've nothing in the log file ...
My mod_auth_kerb version is 5.4-2.2.

Any ideas ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at the output of `apache2ctl -M` on the shell to see whether you've only **installed** or also **activated** the auth module

Comment: Hi Nico and thanks for the quick reply. The first configuration works fine. The output of apache2ctl -M says that `auth_kerb_module (shared)`.